# Why is my arrray of PointF not being updated when I increase a variable that is referenced in the array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array of PointF and each entry references some variables. They're referenced because I'm trying to make a infinite game - pieceWorld is a counter to know how many sections of map have passed and standardDist is just a generic size of a section. When I update pieceWorld and call to get the ground array again, it doesn't actually get updated. Some code:

```
float pieceWorld = 0;
float standardDist = 1600f;
PointF ground[] = { new PointF((pieceWorld * standardDist) + 0f, 289f),
        new PointF((pieceWorld * standardDist) + 67.5f, 289f)}
public void increaseCount(){
    pieceWorld++;
}

public PointF[] getOpeningGround() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ground;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That variable, `pieceWorld`, is not being "referenced" by the array. It's simply being used as a literal being passed to the `PointF` constructor. The value is passed as a copy to the constructor, which does whatever it wants with the copy. Any changes to the passed `pieceWorld` variable will not have any effect on what happens inside the `PointF` instance.

Comment: I see! How would I get around this? Do I have to create new array every time I call for ground? Any other way to do this?

Comment: Well, if PointF is your own class you should just put the logic for manipulation inside the class itself. Then trigger the change externally. For example, you could have a field in the PointF class which corresponds to the `pieceWorld` variable. Then you can create a method to modify this field whenever you want. The method can perform the necessary changes.

Comment: PointF is Android Class that stores 2 floats, but I have the above code in custom class called MyPoints. In another class I create instance of MyPoints, get the first ground array, increase the pieceworld, but I can't get the updated version of ground array the second time around.Sorry for being pain.

Comment: In that case, creating a new array each time would not be unreasonable in my opinion.

Comment: Why don't you extend PointF and just add an increment method?